# Turn on Ethernet by default in AOSP?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

I have AOSP for android 4.2 with Ethernet patch added to it. When I flash android image to my device and boot the device I have to go to settings turn on Ethernet to get started. If I do it the first time I don't have to turn on Ethernet again no matter how many times I restart the device. But my requirement is that Ethernet should be turned on the first time android boots up. I am trying to turn on Ethernet by default but I am unable to find a solution. Can anybody please explain how to enable Ethernet by default in AOSP?